# Flex working with images (converting from and to Bytearray)

Tags: image, apache-flex, flex4, arrays

I'm having a task in which I have to read and save images in the database.

I'm using C#.net Webservice and SQlserver2008 database and I'm saving image as varbinary format.

I want to know

1. How I can read images from local system and convert it into byte array
   in Flex ?
2. How to show images in Flex that are recieved in type Bytearray?

Any tutorials or code examples will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I refered Below Link Nice working fine...

1. How I can read images from local system and convert it into byte array in Flex ?

Answer:

[Loading a local file to a byte array in Flash Player 10 with Flex SDK 3.4+](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Loading_a_local_file_to_a_byte_array_in_Flash_Play-16715.html)

2. How to show images in Flex that are recieved in type Bytearray?

Answer:
 `yourImage.source = yourByteArray;` ([From This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2845286/842112))

Comment: I need some clarification on this answer. Can you ping me for chat?

Answer (score 1):

Please read the following site:

http://blog.yoz.sk/2009/10/bitmap-bitmapdata-bytearray/

It may help.